# Cannot find Subreport from jar file

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have completed my java project through Netbeans with Jasper Report. I copied the files to another laptop and run the jar file, but I get an error when i run the report from the jar file pertaining to the subreport:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jrexception resource not found at ...path
```

It tried to look on the original path of the subreport where I have developed my program and reports. Now, since I want to run the program to another laptop, I dont have that path anymore. What to do? How to set the subreports to a relative path? I have this subreport expression:

```
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "SubReport_Items.jasper"
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** use relative path in jasper report, that's why you normally use `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}`, since the `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` is parameter, your application can use relative path and then pass the absolute path to jasper report es.

***java code example***

```
File reportDir = new File("myReportDirRealtiveToApplication"); //relative path
String absolutePath = reportDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator; //Convert to absolute

Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramMap.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", absolutePath); //Pass as parameter
```

pass the parameter map to your export/fill method, below is an example, naturally you will use what ever you are using currently....

```
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperFileName, paramMap, myConnection); //Fill the report
```

Comment: Hi Petter, thank you for this help. I am only new to java, what should i put in "jasperFileName"? Should that be the filename of my main jasper report (MainReport_Record.jasper)?

Comment: fillReportToFile is only an example to show how the parameter is passed to the report, it is one of many methods on the JasperFileManager, find the correct method you need to use, (generate pdf, doc, ecc) and then check the API to understand what you need to pass (in this case it was the path to the .jasper...)